# Allowing a subview's radius to be larger than its superview's?

Tags: ios, swift, subview, cashapelayer

I've got a rounded button that I'm adding a circular progress ring to using code from here:
http://notebookheavy.com/2014/07/30/ios-7-style-progress-meter-in-swift/

```
var progressCircle = CAShapeLayer();
let centerPoint = CGPoint (x: circle.bounds.width / 2, y: circle.bounds.width / 2);
let circleRadius : CGFloat = circle.bounds.width / 2  // this is what I need to fix * 1.25      
var circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI), clockwise: true    );
circle.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle);
self.view.addSubview(circle)
```

The above code draws a circle around my  button, but I'm wanting instead of the circle to hug the inside of the circumference, I want it to hug the outside. I figured I could just make the radius larger, but once I go beyond width / 2, the subview is no longer visible in the view at all.

How would I allow the radius of the progressCircle to be larger than the button's and appear to be wrapping around the button instead of creating a circle inside of the circumference?

Comment: In your superview set `clipsToBounds = false`.

Comment: @shallowThought Actually, this now makes the button's image extend past the button's radius as well now. I tried setting the button.imageView.clipsToBounds = true but it seems like it gets overridden by the entire thing not clipping to bounds. Any ideas on that?